# Move pods from one nodegroup of 2 nodes to another nodegroup of 3 nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

we have an application deployed on AWS EKS, with these components:

- Apache Artemis JMS
- PostgreSQL
- Kafka
- and some application stateless pods made in node.js

Which is the best approach to move the entire application from one nodegroup to another?

We were thinking to use the "kubectl drain" command and move the EBS manually to the new node.

Is there any better option?

The reason behind this request is that we started with 2 xlarge nodes and we want to move to 4 large nodes, also to have the application on all 3 AWS zones, because we are worried that if a node dies, AWS may start the node on a different zone and EBS disks will not be mounted.

Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 1):

I would just add nodeselectors of nodeaffinity and then delete the running pods (so they will be rescheduled on the correct nodes)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this to use node [taint and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) and redeploy your application to the desired node.